# Is there a URN scheme for using domain names?

Tags: dns, uri, w3c, urn

is there any available hierarchical URN scheme that can use URLs or domain names as "prefixes"?

Best Regrads

Comment: A URN is always going to start with urn: and is not going to be hierarchical. It might be better if you could explain in more detail what you are really asking for and why - how would you use such a URN scheme? When you say prefix do you mean something other than the "urn:" at the start? What would it be like to use a URL as a "prefix"?

Comment: @barefootliam, why can not i have something like urn:stackoverflow.com:question:36411988 to give an id to this question, without saying how to reach it (stackoverflow.com domain name is used to ensure uniqueness)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All URN Namespace Identifiers (NID) are registered here: http://www.iana.org/assignments/urn-namespaces

As it wouldn’t be feasible to create a URN NID for every domain name, it would probably be a single NID with the domain name in the Namespace Specific String (NSS). For example, `urn:example:com:stackoverflow:…`, `urn:example:org:wikipedia:…`.

The problem with this approach is that domain name ownership and/or the content accessible from the corresponding URLs can change over time, but URNs should always refer to the same entity.

There doesn’t seem to be a URN NID for this purpose.

You didn’t describe your use case, but maybe [the `tag` URI scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13948816/1591669) can help. It solves the problem of changing domain ownership and of changing content, but only the domain owner (whether previous owners or the current one) may mint new `tag` URIs. For example, Stack Overflow might generate the following Tag URI for your question:

```
tag:stackoverflow.com,2015:36411988
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is a URN namespace that uses domain names as a prefix, since 2005!

It is the [FDC URN Namespace](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4198), which is of the following form:

```
urn:fdc:<domain_name>:<date>:<id>
```

Examples given in the spec:

```
urn:fdc:example.com:2002:A572007
urn:fdc:example.net:200406:ivr:51089
urn:fdc:example.org:20010527:img089322-038
```

Comment: Very similar to the `tag:` scheme interestingly.