# Is there a NID for URNs, which can be used for fully qualified class names?

Tags: jakarta-ee, urn

Is there a [NID](https://www.iana.org/assignments/urn-namespaces/urn-namespaces.xhtml) for [URN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Name)s, which can be used for fully qualified class names?

I remember to have read something in the context of [J2EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE) some years ago, but do not remember and did not find something using web search.

I found [Is there a URN scheme for using domain names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411988/is-there-a-urn-scheme-for-using-domain-names), but this does not really match, because it contains additionally a mandatory date and resource identifier.